# How to send contact form message to email of smtp server using php mail() function?

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

There is a form in my webpage, message from the contact form goes to an email of a smtp server. I have used this codes for sending the message:

```
require_once("PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$fromName = $_POST['username'];
$fromEmail = $_POST['email'];
$theMessage = $_POST['message'];
$theSubject = $_POST['subject'];
$theCompany = $_POST['company'];
$thePhone = $_POST['phone'];
$isSuccess = 0;
$notificationMsg = "";

$mail = new PHPMailer;
// $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 465;

// Authentication
$mail->Username = 'smtp_username';
$mail->Password = 'smtp_password';

// Compose
$mail->SetFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
$mail->addReplyTo($fromEmail, $fromName);

// Send To
$mail->addAddress('info@mycompany.com', 'My Company');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->isHTML(true);

if ($mail->send()) {
   $isSuccess = 1;

   $notificationMsg = "Thank you for your message";
} else {
   $isSuccess = 0;

   $notificationMsg .= "Sorry, there is something wrong. Please, try again letter.";
   exit ;
}

echo $notificationMsg;
```

But, it didn't work. If I add these line for Compose section:

```
// Compose    
$mail->From = 'user@mycompany.com';  // any email address from our own
```

it will work then! And it shows at our email box:

```
from: Root User <user@mycompany.com>
reply-to:   Sender Name <sender@gmail.com>
to: My Company <info@mycompany.com>
```

Message body at the email box is okay. But, instead of `sender's email` address, `our email` address is showed at `form` field. Also, `Root User` is showed instead of `sender's name`. If I add one more line at compose section:

```
// Compose    
$mail->From = 'user@mycompany.com';  // any email address from our own
$mail->FromName = 'Anything';
```

It shows then:

```
from: Anything <user@mycompany.com>
reply-to:   Sender Name <sender@gmail.com>
to: My Company <info@mycompany.com>
```

Even, I tried with this:

```
// Compose   
$mail->From = $fromEmail;
$mail->FromName = $fromName;
```

But, message won't sent then form my contact form.

So, for compose section,

```
// Compose    
$mail->From = 'user@mycompany.com';  // any email address from our own
$mail->FromName = 'Anything';
$mail->SetFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
$mail->addReplyTo($fromEmail, $fromName);
```

3rd line doesn't seem working. But, that line should be working instead of first two lines and at our email box, it should be shown:

```
from: Sender Name <sender@gmail.com>
reply-to: Sender Name <sender@gmail.com>
to: My Company <info@mycompany.com>
```

How to solve that problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most email providers will classify your email as spam, if you try to “fake” the sender address. Send from an address the SMTP account you are using is allowed to send for, and put the form user’s email address into reply-to, so that whoever receives this can then _answer_ to the correct address automatically.

Comment: Ok, I have gotten the concept for using own email address. But, I am facing a problem with that. Our jira account is configured such a way when a message has been received to our email box, an issue is being created at our Jira issue collector. At that issue, jira is considering our own email address as `Reporter`. So that, reply/comment from that issue in jira goes to our own email address instead of sender's email address. I am not getting solution for that jira issue. That's why, I thought if I could change the Form field at our php code.

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-create-issue-from-email-webpage-form/qaq-p/692362?utm_source=atlcomm&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=accept_as_solution_reminder&utm_content=topic

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to use the submitter's address as the from address; it's forgery and even if you can get away with sending with it (which it looks like you can't anyway), it will cause your messages to fail SPF checks and be spam-filtered or bounced. Put your own address in the from address and the submitter's address in a reply-to, as [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) shows you.

The combination of `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` and `$mail->Port = 465;` will not work; change `Port` to 587 *or* `SMTPSecure` to `ssl`.

Read the docs, base your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer, and update to the latest version.

Comment: Ok, I have gotten the concept for using own email address. But, I am facing a problem with that. Our jira account is configured such a way when a message has been received to our email box, an issue is being created at our Jira issue collector. At that issue, jira is considering our own email address as `Reporter`. So that, reply/comment from that issue in jira goes to our own email address instead of submitter's email address. I am not getting solution for that jira issue. That's why, I thought if I could change the `Form` field at our php code.

Comment: My problem at jira community: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-create-issue-from-email-webpage-form/qaq-p/692362?utm_source=atlcomm&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=accept_as_solution_reminder&utm_content=topic

Comment: So use a different, but still valid address in your domain that doesn't get intercepted by Jira. Sounds like Jira needs an API call that isn't subject to the constraints of SMTP.